# Why are we calling it a moderator "nomination" when it amounts to volunteering?

Tags: discussion, election

Since there's a moderator election about to happen here on sa.se, and since I've been wondering this in general for se sites... doesn't the word *nomination* seem inaccurate? Shouldn't it be labeled as something closer to "now accepting volunteers"?

If you're talking about other places that use that term, like a grammy nod (etc), a nomination is when someone proposes someone else's name/work/etc for an award or privilege.

All aspects of the system totally makes sense and works quite well, but am I the only one that thinks the terminology is a tad off?

Comment: +1 agree - I have no problem with people throwing their own hat into the ring, but it seems to me that is more of a 'I'm running for moderator - vote for me'.  Also, is it even possibile to nominate someone who isn't you?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the definition of *nominate* to suggest that one can't nominate oneself - it's quite a common usage.

On the other hand, it is a little odd in the sense that you *can't* nominate *other* people.  This part actually did confuse me when the first elections began on other sites, especially since the less-formal pro-tem nominations were 3rd-party nominations.

Still, the word *volunteer* implies that anyone who wants the position can have it.  Assuming there are more than 3 candidates, that won't be the case.  This *is* an actual election, and in an election, the candidates are generally called nominees.  It's meant to be analogous to a political election.

The only other word I can think of that would make sense is "bid" - and I think I just used it in a comment - but I can see why the SE team would shun it.  It's kind of slang and might make no sense to non-Americans (or at least non-native English speakers).

Comment: Exactly what I meant, about the "can't". The rest is immaterial, since I'm not proposing an actual change, so that was actually the main issue. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 2):

see:

[Change "nominate" to "volunteer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75438/change-nominate-to-volunteer)

and

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/what-is-the-reason-for-insisting-on-self-nomination/1305#1305