# 2018 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2018 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Why are nominations self-nomination?  It seems like I should be nominating someone *else*.

Comment: @FuzzyChef: Because by self-nominating the candidate indicates that he or she is willing to take on the job. Not everyone *wants* to be a moderator: Your role changes and you are taking on extra responsibilities. If you think that a user would be a good candidate, feel free to encourage them to throw their hat into the ring. See https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/991/why-are-we-calling-it-a-moderator-nomination-when-it-amounts-to-volunteering/993#993

Comment: Thanks, Stephie.